# Deal with Readonly values in ASP.NET (Core) applications and Azure Tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, mapping, azure-table-storage

I have an object like this:

```
class Record 
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; } // ? To SET or not to SET ?
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Record() : this (DateTime.Now) { }
    public Record(DateTime created) { this.Created = created; }
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to expose the `Created` member, as read-only `get;` or with `set;`?

That member is set only once when created (by the constructor), then should be just readonly viewed.

In the Edit View I have problems with this field, because if I expose them as writeable (with `set`) input it tries to update it back or says it's wrong formatted; from the other side if is readonly it does not load properly from the database (azure tables in my case)...

Here is the function that recuperates the Records from the "database" (azure Tables):

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetTableEntitiesAsync<T>(string partition) where T : ITableEntity, new()
{
    TableQuery<T> recordsQuery = new TableQuery<T>().Where(
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partition));
    List<T> myList = new List<T>();

    var items = await this.GetTable<T>().ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<T>(recordsQuery, null);
    myList = items.ToList();

    return myList; // when Readonly all records have Created == DateTime.Now
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use 2 models:

1. Simple DTO class for storing to/retrieving from DB

   ```
   class DBRecord 
   {
      public DateTime Created { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Business model with specific logic like time handling

   ```
   class Record 
   {
      public DateTime Created { get; private set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }

      public Record() { this.Created = DateTime.Now;}

      public Record(DBRecord dbRecord) 
      { 
           this.Name = dbRecord.Name;
           this.Created = dbRecord.Created; 
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: unfortunately the second will not work as I obtain the object via a TableQuery so the properties are filled-in automatically... I don't know what constructor they use, probably the parameterless... so it creates the Created as "Now"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, we could use our logic in the view. Please have a try to use the following logic to do that:

If we try to add the record to the table, there is no created item in the View.
If we try to edit the record we could set the created item disable that means we couldn't edit the created item in the view.

```
public class Record:TableEntity
    {

        public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Record(string pk,string rk,string createDateTime = null)
        {
            PartitionKey = pk;
            RowKey = rk;
            CreatedTime = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(createDateTime) ? DateTime.Parse(createDateTime) : DateTime.Now;
        }


    }
```